# Upgrade SpringBoot 2.3.5 To 2.4.0

Tags: spring-boot, properties, properties-file

I would like to upgrade my SpringBoot version from 2.3.5 to 2.4 but i have problems..

App in 2.3.5 runs without any problem

I updated my POM with this, no errors on POM. :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

I have 4 applications properties like that :
application-local.properties
application-d.yaml
application-...yaml
appl...

I'm in local, so i want to run the application-local.properties.
For that, i was using in "VM arguments" of SpringBootTool :
`-Dspring.profiles.active=local`

Now with that and Spring 2.4.0 it does not apply the local profile and it runs the app without any properties.

For my test :
I have suppressed the VM argument, put `spring.profiles.active=local` in application.properties ( because the application.properties is loaded too with application-local.properties)

I tested with and without `spring.config.activate.on-profile=local` in my application-local.properties

I read those two :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Config-Data-Migration-Guide

Thanks for help !

Comment: Try a application argument instead using `--spring.profiles.active=local` instead of a VM argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is known and is caused by comments in properties

Example :

```
# I'm a comment
custom.properties.url=http://stack.com
# I'm another
```

With a public release > 2.4.0 or use 2.4.1-SNAPSHOT
Refer to this and other related in : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24263

Comment: That should't be the case as he was supplying an system parameter and not reading that from a properties file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved for me after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.4.0 was to use

mvn spring-boot:run **-Dspring-boot.run.profiles**=dev

instead of using -Dspring.profiles.active